# Failed to instantiate class in selenium-cucumber framework

Tags: selenium, cucumber-junit

I am using cucumber 3.0.2.My testrunner code is given below.

```
package futurerx_testrunner_pkg;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="features/login.feature",glue= {"stepdefinition"})

public class testrunner {
}
```

I have created 2 packages in src(futurerx_testrunner_pkg and stepdefinition).I have testrunner.java in futurerx_testrunner_pkg package and Basedefinition.java in stepdefinition package.

But when i am running the code,it gives an error "Failed to instantiate class stepdefinition.Basedefinition at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47) at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33) at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:48)".
I am new to this cucumber-selenium framework and not understanding where i am going wrong.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This may be cause, Check the link for further details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591099/cucumber-runtime-cucumberexception-failed-to-instantiate-class

Comment: Add the code for BaseDefinition

Comment: oops...Its my mistake. I forgotten to change some codes in base defenition after upgading the jar files.Thanks All